# Jquery validation plugin not loading

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am using Jquery Validation Plugin for the first time and despite searching and watching examples I am not being able to implement it. I am trying to validate simple things such as "username" and "password" fields.

The goal is to give user feedback as I progress on the form. If typing an incorrect value it should automatically display the error. Am I supposed to add the ShowErrors() method?

Part of the problem may very well be that I still don't know what are the basic requirements to user the Jquery validation plugin.

Can someone help?

For the following HMTL code (very much a copy of twitter changing password code)  I have the JS below.

HTML:

```
<form id="account-password" class="form-horizontal" id="password-form" method="POST" action="">
    <!--
        <div id="settings-alert-box" class="alert hidden">
        <i id="settings-alert-close" class="close"></i>
        </div>
    -->
    <input value="PUT" name="_method" type="hidden">
    <input name="authenticity_token" value="f6b609b04af68cb4c46128cae7016513ea9062a9" type="hidden">
    <fieldset class="control-group">
        <label for="current_password" id="account3" class="control-label">
            Current password</label>
        <div id="account3" class="controls">
            <input id="current_password" name="current_password" type="password">
            <p>
                <a href="/account/resend_password" id="forgot_password">Forgot your password?</a>
                <span id="reminder_sent" style="visibility: hidden">Reminder sent!</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div id="password-match-pair">
        <fieldset class="control-group">
            <label for="user_password" id="account3" class="control-label">New password</label>
            <div id="password_strength" class="controls">
                <input id="user_password" name="user_password" type="password">
                <small id="password_strength_feedback" class="help-inline help-error" style="display: none;">
                </small>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="control-group">
            <label for="user_password_confirmation" id="account3" class="control-label">Verify password</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="user_password_confirmation" name="user_password_confirmation" type="password">
                <small id="password_match" class="help-inline help-error" style="display: none;">Passwords don't match</small>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button id="submit-data" class="btn btn-info" type="submit" disabled="">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#account-form').validate({

        rules: {

            current_password:{
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            user_password:{
                required: true,
                minlength: 5

            },
            user_password_confirmation:{
                required: true
                equalTo: '#user_password'
            },

        },
        messages: {

            current_passwords:{
                required: 'You need to type of current password',
                    minlength: 'Minimum 5 charaters'
            },
            user_passwords:{
                required: 'Verify password',
                    minlength: 'Minimum 5 charaters'
            },
            user_passwords_confirmation:{
                required: 'You need to type a new password',
                equalTo: 'Passwords dont match'
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though you're not selecting your form with jquery correctly:

change `$('#account-form')` to `$('#account-password')`

http://jsfiddle.net/Mqk5t/

also, in your `messages` configuration take the `s` off of each property as your html id's don't have an s on them

Comment: Regarding the right ID and the extra "s", you are right. Nevertheless, it still doesn't work. :\ (I had previously changed the ID to test with other form though it is the same result

Comment: Did you try out the fiddle above?  The form validation works there.  I tweaked your html a little bit as you were missing some self closing tags.  Not sure if jquery is tripping over that as well.  Try copying the html I used and see if that helps you out.

Comment: I know, it is working. I just copied the html but it is the same. May it be because of CSS and HTML formatting (e.g. not space to display the error, or should the error overlay?)

Comment: can you create a fiddle with your complete page source including javascript and css?

Comment: Sure. I haven't included the CSS though just with the HTML and Javascript it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/crowdfun/uZZZF/

Comment: I added a comma at the end of line 20 of your javascript and an external resource of the plugin you're using : http://jsfiddle.net/uZZZF/2/

Comment: Hey man, you're not going to believe it! Now it is working and the problem, with which I spent one day with, was: file ="jquery.validation.js" and I had <script.... src="validation.js".....oh god. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: glad you figured it out :)